# Shuffling a deck of cards - array or stack?

Tags: java, android, shuffle

Im planning to develop a simple card game on android-Java, in my app i shuffle the cards so i wonder what is the best way to store the deck of my cards in array or in a stack..? The only problem with stack is that i dont know how to shuffle it.

Comment: Shy not shuffle it as an array, then use the array to initialize the stack?

Comment: Be careful with shuffling. It can be tricky to get a fair and secure shuffle (if secure is a requirement). See, for example, [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: I would use an array

Comment: Shuffling a real deck of cards works *nothing* like a stack, so there is no reason to even consider that data structure. Just because the act of dealing cards in the real world is "stack-like" doesn't actually suggest a stack is in any way a good choice for storing a representation of a deck of cards in a computer program. Use an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this will do the trick for a Stack:

```
Stack<Card> deck = new Stack<>();
// add Card types to deck...
Collections.shuffle(deck);
```

Answer (score 1):

A stack in java is a List, so you can call Collections.shuffle, which takes in a List as an argument

Stack deck = new Stack();
.... when ready to shuffle
Collections.shuffle(deck);

A stack extends a Vector, which extends AbstractList and implements List